# Proof of inverse trignometric function for arcsine - self study

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm attempting to prove that:

$$\int {du\over \sqrt {a^2-u^2}} = \text{arcsin}\left({u\over a}\right) + C$$ for $a > 0$

I differentiated the right hand side and came up with

$${dy\over dx} = {{du\over dx}\over \sqrt {a^2 - u^2}}$$

However I feel like I'm missing some theorem or step in order to state that the integral of left side is in fact equal to the right side

Is there a theorem that states

$${d{\int f'(x) dx }\over dx} = f'(x) $$

If so what is that theorem's name?

Comment: The fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: I find it easier to use implicit differentiation to prove the derivative of arcsin is the given function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) says that for a continuous function $g$,
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x g(t)\,dt=g(x).$$
Now, this works in particular with your function $g(x)=f'(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

The expression $\int {du\over\sqrt{a^2-u^2}}$ (indefinite integral) is *notation* for "all functions whose derivative is ${1\over\sqrt{a^2-u^2}}$. So the verification of what you are asked to show is no more nor less than checking that the derivative of $\arcsin(u/a)+C$ is ${1\over\sqrt{a^2-u^2}}$, regardless of the value of $C$.